# Including currency symbols in solr / lucene indexes

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize

Is it possible to index a text field considering currency symbols as separate tokens?
For example in a text field I have this:

```
"16 €"
```

and I need to build an index with this entries:

```
16
€
```

In order to search for "€" and finding the document.

Now I'm using StandardTokenizer and it discards currency symbols.

A possible solution could be using a more "trivial" tokenizer such as the WhitespaceTokenizer but I think it will get worse tokenization on other text.

Note that the problem is not how to index currencies, this is a trivial example but in the field i could have an arbitrary text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, albeit not very pretty, is to replace the eurosign with something the tokenizer you've chosen will leave alone. You [can use a MappingCharFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory) to replace the eurosign with a string like EUROSIGN, and then replace it after tokenization again.

Unless you're able to formally express exactly how you want your tokenizer to work, you'll have to go with one of the preset versions that are suitable for most content to give usable search results. If you have a more specific rule set, writing your own tokenizer in Java is an option.